# SEO script/link to another website

Tags: seo, html, pagerank

I am improving my centralized CMS system design. Till now, all the CSS, images, javascript were loading from the central domain name, i.e. domain a.com, c.com, d.com CSS/JS/images loads from b.com.

I was wondering whether this have any effect on the SEO? as in, pagerank, backlinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than SEO, it helps in improving your page performance (CDN - Content Delivery Network) which loads CSS/JS/Images parallelly. I don't think having different domain pointing to the same IP can have an effect with backlinks/pagerank.

**PageRank**

> PageRank is a link analysis algorithm, with the purpose of "measuring" its relative importance within the set

**Backlinks**

> Backlinks (or back-links [UK]) are incoming links to a website or web page. Inbound links were originally important (prior to the emergence of search engines) as a primary means of web navigation; today their significance lies in search engine optimization (SEO).

Answer (score 0):

Loading your static files from a CDN or different domain will have no effect on your PageRank. PageRank is solely calculated on a page's link popularity. The files included on your page and their location relative to the page is irrelevant.

Loading your static files from a CDN or different domain won't *directly* affect your rankings. But doing this does theoretically make your site load faster. Page load speed is a ranking factor for Google (although definitely a small one and only affects 1% of websites so it probably only affects sites that load extremely slow).